# JHDF5 - How to avoid dataset being overwritten

Tags: java, hdf5

I am using JHDF5 to log a collection of values to a hdf5 file. I am currently using two ArrayLists to do this, one with the values and one with the names of the values.

```
ArrayList<String> valueList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();

valueList.add("Value1");
valueList.add("Value2");
nameList.add("Name1");
nameList.add("Name2");

IHDF5Writer writer = HDF5Factory.configure("My_Log").keepDataSetsIfTheyExist().writer();    
HDF5CompoundType<List<?>> type = writer.compound().getInferredType("", nameList, valueList);        

writer.compound().write("log1", type, valueList);       
writer.close();
```

This will log the values in the correct way to the file My_Log and in the dataset "log1". However, this example always overwrites the previous log of the values in the dataset "log1". I want to be able to log to the same dataset everytime, adding the latest log to the next line/index of the dataset. For example, if I were to change the value of `"Name2"` to `"Value3"` and log the values, and then change `"Name1"` to `"Value4"` and `"Name2"` to `"Value5"` and log the values, the dataset should look like this:

[image]

I thought the `keepDataSetsIfTheyExist()` option to would prevent the dataset to be overwritten, but apparently it doesn't work that way.

Something similar to what I want can be achieved in some cases with `writer.compound().writeArrayBlock()`, and specify by what index the array block shall be written. However, this solution doesn't seem to be compatible with my current code, where I have to use lists for handling my data.

Is there some option to achieve this that I have overlooked, or can't this be done with JHDF5?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that will work. It is not quite clear to me, but I believe the getInferredType() you are using is creating a data set with 2 name -> value entries. So it is effectively creating an object inside the hdf5. The best solution I could come up with was to read the previous values add them to the valueList before outputting:

```
    ArrayList<String> valueList = new ArrayList<>();

    valueList.add("Value1");
    valueList.add("Value2");

    try (IHDF5Reader reader = HDF5Factory.configure("My_Log.h5").reader()) {
        String[] previous = reader.string().readArray("log1");
        for (int i = 0; i < previous.length; i++) {
            valueList.add(i, previous[i]);
        }
    } catch (HDF5FileNotFoundException ex) {
        // Nothing to do here.
    }

    MDArray<String> values = new MDArray<>(String.class, new long[]{valueList.size()});
    for (int i = 0; i < valueList.size(); i++) {
        values.set(valueList.get(i), i);
    }

    try (IHDF5Writer writer = HDF5Factory.configure("My_Log.h5").writer()) {
        writer.string().writeMDArray("log1", values);
    }
```

If you call this code a second time with "Value3" and "Value4" instead, you will get 4 values. This sort of solution might become unpleasant if you start to have hierarchies of datasets however.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Alas, this is not the setup I was looking for, and perhaps I was too vague in my question (which I will edit later when I have time). The key thing is that the values need to correspond to the names. When I write to my log file, the values should be inserted in a new row and each value in their corresponding name column.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your issue, you need to define the dataset `log1` as extendible so that it can store an unknown number of log entries (that are generated over time) and write these using a point or hyperslab selection (otherwise, the dataset will be overwritten).

If you are not bound to a specific technology to handle HDF5 files, you may wish to give a look at [HDFql](https://www.hdfql.com) which is an high-level language to manage HDF5 files easily. A possible solution for your use-case using HDFql (in Java) is:

```
public class Example
{

    public Class Log
    {
        String name1;
        String name2;
    }

    public boolean doSomething(Log log)
    {
        log.name1 = "Value1";
        log.name2 = "Value2";
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        // declare variables
        Log log = new Log();
        int variableNumber;

        // create an HDF5 file named 'My_Log.h5' and use (i.e. open) it
        HDFql.execute("CREATE AND USE FILE My_Log.h5");

        // create an extendible HDF5 dataset named 'log1' of data type compound
        HDFql.execute("CREATE DATASET log1 AS COMPOUND(name1 AS VARCHAR, name2 AS VARCHAR)(0 TO UNLIMITED)");

        // register variable 'log' for subsequent usage (by HDFql)
        variableNumber = HDFql.variableRegister(log);

        // call function 'doSomething' that does something and populates variable 'log' with an entry
        while(doSomething(log))
        {
            // alter (i.e. extend) dataset 'log1' to +1 (i.e. add a new row)
            HDFql.execute("ALTER DIMENSION log1 TO +1");

            // insert (i.e. write) data stored in variable 'log' into dataset 'log1' using a point selection
            HDFql.execute("INSERT INTO log1[-1] VALUES FROM MEMORY " + variableNumber);
        }
    }

}
```